# How to align the origin in a 3-d figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to set origins in x and y axis same in a 3-d figure using matplotlib. However, I cannot do this. My code is:

```
axs.set_xlim([-60, 60])
axs.set_ylim([-60, 60])
```

I also try:

```
plt.xlim([-60, 60])
plt.xlim([-60, 60])
```

both of them are not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-60, 60)
ax.set_ylim(-60, 60)
ax.set_zlim(-60, 60)
```

Comment: I used Axes3D，do you think the difference between Axes3D and projection=3d lead my failure? I am a rookie, thank you

Comment: I found it also not work, i give up and use matlab to draw the figure. however, thank you for your attention

Comment: I actually don't know the difference but the above code works for me to set the origin point

Comment: I have search the datasheet，finding the two thing is same, when we use the projection, in fact, it call the Axes3D in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem not exist in matlab, so if you meet the problem, I suggest you use matlab to realize your aim